# Druid : No column with timestamp with local time-zone type on query result; one column should be of timestamp with local time-zone type

Tags: hive, druid

I am trying to create a druid table based on existing druid table using below query for which I'm facing error.

query :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.druid_table2 STORED BY 
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.druid.DruidStorageHandler' AS SELECT '__time' as `__time`,column1, column2, column3 FROM database.druid_table1;
```

error :

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: 
    SemanticException No column with timestamp with local time-zone type on query result; one column 
    should be of timestamp with local time-zone type
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:300)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:286)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:324)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:26`enter code here`5)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:718)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:801)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:103)
    at 
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:633)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

NOTE : I'm using Hive interactive mode since this is a druid related query and Hadoop version is 3.2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this method or syntax, but judging from the error it works for other cases?  If so, perhaps you have to cast __time into a format indicating timezone?  I'm not sure how it's being passed.